# How to open a command prompt and input different commands from a java program

Tags: java, command, derby

I need to open a command prompt & execute `ij.bat`, which will take me to another prompt, where I can give command to connect to DB & later different sql statements. I was able to execute `ij.bat` from the java program like

`Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\ij.bat");`

But how to give the furthur set of commands through the java program?

Comment: I think you may try `Robot` to do this. To give command on opened command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this   `exec
public Process exec(String command)
              throws IOException`

Also visit [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122850/use-cmd-commands-in-java-program)

Comment: My Scenario is 
`cmd> ij.bat`
`ij> connect '..\db\mall';`
`ij> select * from users;`

Comment: Please visit the link in my answer

Comment: I cheked that. It has the details on how to read the output one command executed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to run ij.bat, and feed it commands to run and parse the output, just have your program use the ij class, and its runScript method: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/publishedapi/org/apache/derby/tools/ij.html#runScript-java.sql.Connection-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-java.io.OutputStream-java.lang.String-

Then you don't have to spawn a separate process, but can just keep everything in pure Java in your program itself.